# Disable AJAX loading icon from WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

Im using an UpdatePanel with a timer and when the timer fires I get a animated .gif from webresource.axd that never goes away so I end up with multiplying .gif's. How do I disable this animation?

Comment: This must be added from some custom control, or other resource of you, because UpdatePanel did not have loading icon by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom message you your UpdatePanel like that:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProcess" 
       runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="YourProblematicPanelD">
    <ProgressTemplate>
            Left it emtpy, or type something here
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

This UpdateProgress can be outside the Panel.

Anyway as I say there is no default wait icon for the update panel, search to find how they add it in your page

Comment: Ended being an issue with a Rich Text Editor and set a property on the control. Thanks for the help.